# SpringData social integration

Tags: spring-data, spring-social

I am trying to use spring social in a SpringMVC+SpringData+GoogleCloudSQL application. I am following the quick start guide https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/wiki/Quick-Start. I have my Spring Data repository for user and I have not used any custom datasource anywhere in my application.

Spring Social's UsersConnectionRepository has only one implementation i.e. JdbcUsersConnectionRepository. My question is that how can I get rid of this additional datasource and use my own UserRepository or springdata based repository to use Spring-Social?

In short, I am looking for Spring Data-based implementations of Spring Social-related repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Social provides built-in implementation only for one most common scenario (DB used over JDBC). The same policy is used for other projects (for example Spring Security). If you want some additional persistence capabilities (Spring Data, NoSql, etc...) then you need to code corresponding implementations yourself. You can provide implementatations for UsersConnectionRepository and ConnectionRepository interfaces and then use your spring data repositories for persistance needs.